# how to differentiate between simple command and habit which which has been said in simple present tense?

Tags: american-english, british-english, tenses, present-tense

consider sentence:-

"You do this."

i can interpret this in two ways:-

1. I am asking someone to do something (it is request but not so polite).
2. I am talking about his usual habit like "he always does this".

then how to indicate in which sense i am talking in?

Comment: Quite often, by context.

Comment: It has to do mostly with intonation.

Comment: Asking and commanding are not the same thing.

Comment: yeah, but sometime context is little of to the times when you want to use these sentence, and ya, i am not commanding i am asking! it seems there is no straight forward way, in Hindi we differentiate often by our voice tone, anyway thanks.

Comment: When your mother uses your full name it is a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You do this* is text (a string of words)  that usually acts as some sort of message from one entity to another, often from one person to another. Since this same string of three words can encode different messages–such as (1) talking about the regular habits of the person you're talking to, and (2) asking or commanding your interlocutor to perform some action–the string is inherently ambiguous in meaning (even if it has definable syntactic parts).

So, you cannot properly interpret its meaning on its own. Which seems a weird way to attempt to interpret any sentence, since all sentences occur in a certain context and usually as part of a communicative discourse.

Context is of extreme importance. Without context, we have no idea  who *you* is, what *this* is and what action *do* refers to.

Perceived speaker's intention is also important  because according to you, your statement is meant to  "ask someone to do something." That's fine if your interlocutor recognizes this. But your request is encoded in an imperative form,   not an interrogative form.

The communicative discourse will aid tremendously in proper interpretation of your sentence. Basically ask *what function* is the sentence meant to accomplish? If the  intended function has been misinterpreted, it might be because the intended function was not made clear.

As in your (native?) language Hindi, English speakers "differentiate often by our voice tone." Body language is also important.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, this sentence is difficult to parse. As others have suggested, context is paramount. However, punctuation is also important.

In the first example, it is probably better to write something like:

> Please do this.
>   Can you do this?

However, your original phrasing is probably acceptable in a conversation.

> Here, you do this.

In your second example, it would be helpful to frame it as an example.

> For example, you have done this: post questions about English language on Stack Exchange.

Comment: The sentence “You do this” is absolutely not difficult to parse. It is a very, very simple sentence which can be parsed by any speaker in a matter of milliseconds. It may be difficult to semantically _interpret_ it unambiguously, but parsing it into a subject, a matrix verb, and an object is easy as pie. (P.S.: Highlighting text by indenting it is meant for computer code only. Here you’re quoting [imagined] text/speech, so the blockquote formatting is much more apt; it also removes the necessity for quote marks. I’ve changed it for you.)